# how to store a mysql substring selected value into a php variable?

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to differrent solutions:
First:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(EVENTNAAME, 1) FROM EVENTS WHERE DATE >= CURDATE()
```

AND

SECOND:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(EVENTNAAME, 1, 1) FROM EVENTS WHERE DATE >= CURDATE()
```

Both worked in phpMyAdmin, but in my php-file the result is empty because it can't be stored into a variable.

I have done this:

```
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_object ( $result) ) {
     $title = $row->EVENTNAME;
}
```

the var_dump delievers:

```
object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["LEFT(EVENTNAME, 1)"]=> string(1) "S" }
```

but the variable is empty. If I make a select without substring or left the name of the events is fully shown.

But I only want to show the first character of the eventname and use it as title.Therefore I use distinct because if there are more thane one event with the same first letter it delivers only one result.

But this isn't my problem. My problem is how can I store this into a php variable and why does it work if I don't use left or substring with the complete name of the event?

Sorry for bad english and I hope you can help.

Comment: what is the error you face?

Answer (score 0):

Use AS:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(EVENTNAME, 1) AS EVENTNAME FROM EVENTS WHERE DATE >= CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to alias your field names. Once you apply formulates or otherwise create "derivative" values of a field in a query, the field's name is NOT what php will see as a name when it fetches the rows, e.g:

```
SELECT foo, AVG(foo), SUM(foo), ...
```

would (not really, just for example) produce

```
$row['foo'], $row['AVG(foo)'], $row['SUM(foo)']
```

in your result row.

If you alias the fields, then you have total control over how the field's name appears in the results:

```
SELECT foo, AVG(foo) AS argle, SUM(foo) AS bargle
                     ^^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^^^^
$row['foo'], $row['argle'], $row['bargle']
```